# How to change the positioning of one category in ggplot from top to bottom while keeping the order of the cells?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization

Although it seems to me a small issue, but i cannot get my head around it. I have the following data with three main variables: i) education (factor): represents three different level of education(1, 2, 3). ii) share (numeric): represents the % of people in the country for each level of education. iii) country (factor): represents 30 countries.

I plot the share of education in each country by re_ordering the lowest level of education by countries that have the lowest share in it to the ones that have the highest. The issue is while ggplot plot the order right, I would like the same positioning of the below upper-secondary (red color) to show at the bottom of the graph instead of at the top. It is more intuitive to read the graph in the order of below-upper secondary (bottom), upper-secondary (middle), tertiary (top). Could someone please guide through it?

Here is the code:

```
x$lab <- as.character(x$cntry2)
x$country = as.numeric(x$cntry2)
x$educ2= x$educ
x$educ = as.integer(x$educ)
x$educ = as.factor(x$educ)


labs <- x[!duplicated(x$country),]
labs <- labs[,c('country','lab')]

country_order <- x %>% 
  filter(educ == 1) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_reorder(factor(country), share, .desc = FALSE)) %>% 
  pull(country) %>%
  levels()
df2 <- x %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(factor(country), country_order))


ggplot(df2, aes(x=country, y=share)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=educ2), color = "black") +
  labs(fill= "educ") +   
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Country")+ ylab("%") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labs$lab[match(country_order,labs$country)]) +
  theme( 
    legend.position="bottom",
  )
```

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(educ = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), cntry2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L), .Label = c("AU", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", 
    "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GR", "HR", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", 
    "LT", "LU", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PO", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SK", "SV", 
    "UK"), class = "factor"), share = c(14.9585723390695, 64.8311026131294, 
    20.2103250478011, 20.3203525363306, 37.9050825638106, 41.7745648998589, 
    20.5482068669118, 58.6719831908696, 20.7798099422186, 11.0478359908884, 
    52.7334851936219, 36.2186788154898, 24.5876872718117, 41.546015359436, 
    33.8662973687524, 8.1806499751285, 77.2156358812801, 14.6037141435914, 
    18.43684842358, 44.6831364124597, 36.8800151639603, 13.0409077472315, 
    58.1917820678991, 28.7673101848694, 42.6745525429736, 24.1881534644693, 
    33.1372939925571, 16.4818187731737, 46.3084628894816, 37.2097183373447, 
    22.0091736220768, 47.7329122490413, 30.2579141288819, 31.6958715347475, 
    40.8370856615852, 27.4670428036673, 19.5171138871772, 65.7890314268108, 
    14.693854686012, 15.620426612099, 63.1486925776748, 21.2308808102263, 
    27.79203576455, 33.4878715125424, 38.7200927229075, 29.0666986564299, 
    41.950575815739, 28.9827255278311, 36.0270124068613, 47.1984225312789, 
    16.7745650618598, 8.18044159594323, 60.960664858964, 30.8588935450928, 
    37.0050817095017, 37.4766935985084, 25.5182246919899, 15.7399902739504, 
    59.1482759419216, 25.111733784128, 19.2624176167015, 43.4944817814291, 
    37.2431006018693, 17.6501727404436, 44.6784798840967, 37.6713473754597, 
    10.0113985848549, 69.2765124631697, 20.7120889519754, 64.5252051582649, 
    21.4536928487691, 14.021101992966, 21.8502998519559, 62.6627857375856, 
    15.4869144104584, 11.4840104928012, 55.3435190932938, 33.172470413905, 
    4.21056255594574, 74.1410176960683, 21.648419747986, 15.6869892409901, 
    61.3851490387442, 22.9278617202657, 14.2357801080394, 49.3703276303246, 
    36.393892261636), lab = c("AU", "AU", "AU", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
    "BG", "BG", "BG", "CH", "CH", "CH", "CY", "CY", "CY", "CZ", "CZ", 
    "CZ", "DK", "DK", "DK", "EE", "EE", "EE", "ES", "ES", "ES", "FI", 
    "FI", "FI", "FR", "FR", "FR", "GR", "GR", "GR", "HR", "HR", "HR", 
    "HU", "HU", "HU", "IE", "IE", "IE", "IS", "IS", "IS", "IT", "IT", 
    "IT", "LT", "LT", "LT", "LU", "LU", "LU", "LV", "LV", "LV", "NL", 
    "NL", "NL", "NO", "NO", "NO", "PO", "PO", "PO", "PT", "PT", "PT", 
    "RO", "RO", "RO", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SK", "SK", "SK", "SV", "SV", 
    "SV", "UK", "UK", "UK"), country = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
    10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
    15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 
    22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 
    27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30), educ2 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Below upper-secondary", 
    "Upper-secondary", "Tertiary"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -87L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_rev` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(x=country, y=share, 
              fill = forcats::fct_rev(factor(as.integer(educ2))))) + 
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  labs(fill= "educ")  +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Country")+ ylab("%") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

I have removed the code for filtering and labelling of x-axis to keep this simple. You can add that in as in your post if needed.

---

To just reverse the color you can use `position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)`

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=country, y=share, 
              fill = factor(as.integer(educ2)))) + 
  geom_col(color = "black", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  labs(fill= "educ")  +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Country")+ ylab("%") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, i tried it in my code and it did not work. Do you think i should include it somewhere earlier in the code?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Did it work for you as expected for the data shared in this post?

Comment: What i mean is that the categories did not reverse. The red color is still at the top and the blue color is still at the bottom. The end point is to reverse them, but didn't happen

Comment: The color in the legends have been reversed not the color of the bar graph.

Comment: I am sorry if i explained it wrong, but i want the color of the bar graph, not the legend

Comment: I see, okay. See updated answer to reverse the color of the bar graph and not the legend.